# Bottle.py not reloading

Tags: python, windows, bottle

So... trying to follow along the [Bottle To-Do list tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html), using [WinPython 3.4.3](https://winpython.github.io/).  Basically, I was having fits with the script not reloading, despite having

```
run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True)
```

set at the end of the file.  After trying the same tutorial @ home with no problems (using Linux), I figured the problem had to be somewhere in the form of Python that I'm using.  I was using Spyder, but reverted to running the script directly from the command line, and noticed that it appears to not be exiting cleanly when it reloads and/or when the script is stopped, as I'm getting an error like this:

```
E:\python\data\bottle-todo>E:\python\WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\bottle.py:3113: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=268, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 8080)> server.run(app)
```

I can get things working if I look up and kill any running python processes, and then remove the `reloader=True` argument to `run()`... but that seems like fixing the symptom, not the problem.  FWIW, I still get the same error message when I terminate the running script with `CTRL+C`, but it seems to actually terminate - unlike with the reloader.

Question is... is this a bottle.py problem with the reloader under python3.4 + windows, or WinPython, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some processes launched via "spyder 2.3.4 version in Winpython" in a separate process don't want to die when they should.

I'm really not sure where is the problem, but your issue looks a little bit like mine, so:

- bottle and Windows seem not the guilty parties.
- spyder 2.3.5 or recent Winpython or other recent package may be at fault.

I think my issue didn't exist under Winpython3.4.3.1.